# Not able to code for EF 6 calling stored procedure with output parameters?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm new to using EF to call a stored procedure and I've been searching and trying different code to no avail. After looking through different samples and the following code is the closest I've come up with that I think should work.

I'm getting a design time error the following line. On my line `ValidateCSPolicyResult`, this error occurs:

> ValidateCSPolicyResult is a type, which is not valid in the given context

I made sure I have a using statement at the top of the class that points to the folder where the following class is:

```
public class ValidateCSPolicyResult
{
    public string IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code that I'm trying to call. The stored procedure has two output values.

```
using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{
    var empId = new SqlParameter("@empId", employeeId);
    var startDate = new SqlParameter("@startDate", startDateTime);
    var endDate = new SqlParameter("@endDate", endDateTime);
    var swapEmpId = new SqlParameter("@swapEmpId", swapEmployeeId);

    var isValid = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "Valid",
        Value = "N",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    var remarks = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "Remarks",
        Value = "",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    var results = ctx.Database.SqlQuery(ValidateCSPolicyResult)("VALIDATE_CSW_POLICY  @empId, @startDate, @endDate, @swapEmpId, @Valid out, @Remarks out");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in your code block, it should be

```
var results = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<ValidateCSPolicyResult>("VALIDATE_CSW_POLICY  @empId, @startDate, @endDate, @swapEmpId, @Valid out, @Remarks out");
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for catching that. Now I just need to see if I can get it to run.